# Nginx Site File Location

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm attempting to deploy a new (first-time) Nginx server on Ubuntu. I am following [DigitalOcean's tutorial, found here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3).

As the tutorial suggests, I am place each site on the host inside `/var/www/domain.tld`. The issue I am running into comes up when I try to use git: some of the sites are stored in git repos, but trying to use sudo with git is causing permissions errors (on the git end). What I am looking for is a secure way to allow my user account access to the site directories without going through sudo. I do not want to use a directory in my user's home folder (such as `~/var/www` as this makes the site dependent on my user). Where is a reasonably standardized place to store the sites that is user accessible?

Comment: you can keep your files anywhere you want, http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: Question is a "best practice" question. I can in theory store files anywhere, but as a new user of Nginx, I want to know where is reasonably standard. Reworded question.

Answer (score 1):

Use sudo to assign ownership of the directories that site files will live in.  E.g. /var/www/example.com/public_html (using the naming scheme from the tutorial you reference).  You might want to assign ownership of other directories inside /var/www/example.com, but if you have for instance a /var/www/example.com/logs directory then this directory and it's parent directory should be owned by root, and not writable by anyone else.

The tutorial you reference has a rather simplistic permissions model, which won't get you far if a user who does not have access to doing things as the www-data user or as root needs to install files in the web-root.  Furthermore, as far as possible you want to prevent the www-data user from being able to write to code files.

There's a simple strategy, fairly common for shared hosting systems where there's a user for each site, which owns the files, and the web server account accesses the files based on the 'other' user permissions on the file.  This would mean that all users can see all the web files of other users, but often there's also a limitation imposed on what can be seen through the file access server in use (e.g. ftpd or ssh's internal-sftp).  That inhibits users from looking at each others files, without being strong security.  Stronger measures are possible, but not really through just the file permissions.

The www-data user will need to be able to write to some directories (where files get uploaded), but ideally you want the user to be able to prohibit the web server from writing to other directories.  The user can control this through the 'writeable' bit for 'other' users.  i.e. `chmod o+x ...` or `chmod o-x ...`.

Run git as the user which owns the site, only for directories which are writeable by that user.

For a slightly more sophisticated model which allows for sharing site directories between multiple users (and saves them from having to go out of their way to switch to the site user), you might want to look at http://andrew.mcnaughty.com/node/1

You might also want to look into having a system where changes pushed to the appropriate git branch are automatically checked out to the site, which means users only have to worry about git access rather than access to the site user.  Search for 'push to deploy git' to find more on that.

Answer (score 0):

/var/www is fine if you are expecting only a single site on this server.

If you are planning on more than one site (i.e. more than one "server" stanza in nginx) then I'd suggest /var/www/, or some other similar structure.

Stay out of /home if at all possible, for site content.

I'm not sure how this relates to git though; you'll have to be a bit more explicit in describing what the problem is.  If I may hazard a guess, it may be permissions related?  If so, remember, if you own the server, there's now reason /var/www *must* be owned by root, that's just the initial default (usually?  Maybe... it might vary).  It could be owned by a non-root user that is the one you use to deploy content to with git, be that your own user code (but that's not recommended as it conflates the concept of interactive users with service-type users), or perhaps a "deploy" user that owns deployed code/content.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have edited the question to make a little more sense (one of those good old hours at a terminal and way too tired kind of questions).

Answer (score 0):

While this is certainly not the one solution, it seems to have worked for me:

I initially tried adding my user to the `www-data` group (`/var/www` was owned by `www-data:www-data`), however I didn't want to give the www-data group write/execute permissions to protect against security issues involving other system users in `www-data`.

In the end, I ended up setting my personal admin account as the owner of `/var/www` (and its subdirectories). I feel like this is far from the best solution, so I am still open to better ideas, but for the time being, making myself the owner of the entire directory has allowed me to run git there while not opening what look like nay major security holes. This solution still feels a little dependent on the user, but it does feel better than placing the web files in something as heavily-edited and user-dependent as `/home`.

Comment: I see no problem with this, but I do want to remind you that you can create more than one user account on the server!

Comment: I considered multiple users, but due to the issues with needing to run git from the current user account, it seemed like creating a new user would just make the directory dependent on that user instead and still not resolve the git issue. Ultimately I didn't want to change the owner away from `www-data`, but I ended up doing so and it resolved my issue.